# For each result return by SQL query I want as to give a different name

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

My SQL statement looks like

```
SELECT beds.id,beds.name,beds.brand,beds.price,beds.disprice,feature.feature AS feature 
FROM beds,feature,bedFeatures 
WHERE bedFeatures.featureID = feature.id AND bedFeatures.bedID = beds.id
```

I get this result

```
id  name        brand   price   disprice    feature
10  Big Sleeper ZZZZ    10000   1           Oak
10  Big Sleeper ZZZZ    10000   1           Ash
10  Big Sleeper ZZZZ    10000   1           White
```

What I want is for the AS to give each feature a unique name such as feature1 feature2 feature3 so those 4 lines are displyaed in one. Is this possible?

The output I am looking for would look something like

```
id  name        brand   price   disprice    feature1 feature2 feature3
10  Big Sleeper zzzz    1000    1           Oak      Ash      White
```

Comment: What you're asking for is called a _pivot table_. Please post an example of the output you hope to achieve, as it isn't clear right now which other columns you would be including.

Comment: Updated. Hope this helps

Comment: [Is there a limit to the number of features something can have?]

Comment: Yeah there are 4 features product

Comment: Are all the possible values for features known ahead of time? How many are there?

Comment: They will be added in to the DB when the product is created and there are 4 per product

Comment: why not to wrap ypur code a bit, making it readable for the people whom you asked for help?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The exact output you request is not easily achieved, except by using `GROUP_CONCAT()` to list the features as a comma-separated list rather than individual columns.

Because there is not a fixed set of possible features common to all your products, you will not be able to use a pivot query.

I would recommend using `GROUP_CONCAT()` to retrieve the features as a comma-separated list, and then splitting them apart with PHP in your application layer.

```
SELECT
  beds.id,
  beds.name,
  beds.brand,
  beds.price,
  beds.disprice,
  GROUP_CONCAT(feature) AS features
FROM
  beds
  JOIN bedFeatures ON beds.id = bedFeatures.bedID
  JOIN features ON features.id = bedFeatures.featureID
GROUP BY beds.id, beds.name, beds.brand, beds.price, disprice
```

The output of this will look like:

```
d  name        brand   price   disprice    features
10  Big Sleeper zzzz    1000    1           Oak,Ash,White
```

In your PHP, when fetching the results, `explode()` the features into an array:

```
$resultset = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
  // First append the whole row onto the result set as it is...
  $resultset[$row['id']] = $row;
  // Overwrite the `features` string with an array instead...
  $resultset[$row['id']]['features'] = explode(",", $row['features']);
}
```

Finally, access the features in your application as:

```
foreach ($resultset as $r) {
  echo $r['features'][0];
  echo $r['features'][1];
  echo $r['features'][2];
  echo $r['features'][3];
}
```

Comment: For some reason this gives me a char array when I am printing in the foreach

Comment: @SamMarland The explode() call was missing its comma delimiter. Changed above to `explode(",", $row['features']);`

Comment: The line looks like this    $resultset[$row['id']['features'] = explode(",", $row['features']); Should it look like $resultset[$row['id']['featues']] = explode ("'",$row['features');

Comment: Actually, `$resultset[$row['id']]['featues']` Close the bracket after `$row['id']`

Comment: Sorry for all the bugs, but it's tough to spot all of them when rapidly typing into an SO answer box. :)

Comment: Ah right, it's no problem I'm just glad for an answer I have been hacking around for a week just didn't know what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`GROUP_CONCAT`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat).

Comment: This gives you a string though and I am looking for them to be in separate. so I can access them using feature1 feature2 feature 3